# Why Xamarin downgrade Forms versión when i try yo update GooglePlayServices.Maps

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, nuget-package

I have to update my Xamarin project with múltiple solutions (android, iOS, winPhone). So i use the Manage NuGet Packages, when i try to update the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps package, VS shows me this

[image]

Why Xamarin.Forms decrease the versión?

Answer (score 0):

> Why Xamarin.Forms decrease the versión?

The latest `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Map`(32.961) requires the latest `Xamarin.Android.Support 24.2.1`, which is not compatible with `Xamarin.Forms.2.3.1` yet.

So currently, it is not a good idea to update `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Map` to the latest version in `Xamarin.Forms` project.